# espresso dependencies always confusing what to add

Tags: android, android-espresso

```
Android Studio 2.1 Preview 5
```

I am using wondering what should I be including in my `build.gradle` file to use espresso. Everything I google I get different combinations of dependencies to include.

I have people do this:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
```

And from this web site `https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/`

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

Can anyone give a standard way I should be following?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: naively, I would suggest following the instructions given by the people who provide espresso rather than apparently outdated information given by just people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version of espresso you are using. `testing-support-lib:0.1` [was correct](http://wiki.android-test-kit.googlecode.com/git-history/6fc43cd5716a9da9d6c7c40f6728fa1a31a7798c/EspressoSetupInstructions.wiki) for the (older) version 2.0.

If you want to use Espresso 2.2.2, this is correct:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

For newer versions, instructions will be updated [here](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/).